# Add batch file to PATH

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

I'm trying to run a .bat file globally by adding the directory which contains it to PATH. This obviously works for exe files but is there a way to run .bat files this way?

Comment: Yes; that will just work.

Comment: You're right, it seems to see that its there but the script doesn't seem to actually work. If I cd into the directory and run it from there it does.

Comment: What's the path say?

Comment: Path has the right directory in it. I have a bat and an exe in the same place. I can run the exe just fine but the bat doesn't seem to work properly. Now, the bat actually runs the exe file. Could it be that it doesn't know where to find the exe since I'm not running the bat from the directory that the exe is located in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @SLaks said in his comment, this will work.

Based on the rest of your comments, you need to specify the full file name.  If there's `program.exe` and `program.bat`, you need to enter `program.bat` and not just `program` at the command prompt.

When you enter `program` at a command prompt, the shell will first try to execute `program.com`, then `program.exe`, then `program.bat`.  The exact order is saved in the `PATHEXT` environment variable:

```
C:\Windows>echo %PATHEXT%
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Original MS-DOS didn't have this variable, as I recall.  It searched .COM, .EXE, and then .BAT so the behavior has preserved since MS-DOS 3.3 (and I believe since IBM DOS 1.0), but I believe it was hard-coded.  The `PATHEXT` variable was introduced with Windows NT, IIRC.

---

Edit to add:

Ah, alright.  It sounds like your batch file also needs to change to it's own directory so that the current working directory is wherever it's at.  The easy way to do that is at the beginning of the batch file (after your `@echo off`) put:

```
pushd %~dp0
```

This will change the current working directory to wherever the batch file is.  And then at the very last line:

```
popd
```

That will change the current working directory to what ever the current working directory was before the last time that `pushd` was run.

The two commands, [`pushd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx) and [`popd`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490969.aspx), are like advanced change directory commands.  If you're at `C:\` and you type `pushd C:\Program Files\`, you'll change to that directory.  Then if you type `popd`, you'll go back where you just were at C:.  You can do it multiple times, each time "pushing" another directory onto the "stack" of your directory history.  `popd` then removes the top of the stack, and takes you back one.  Think of it like the back button on your browser.  You can even change the drive at the same time.  `pushd D:\` will change to the D: drive and set the directory to the root of D:.

Now, the `%~dp0` is a bit weirder.  It's a *modified variable*.

You might know that the arguments for a batch file get assigned to special variables.  `%1` is the first argument, then `%2` is the second, `%3` the third, and so forth up to `%9`.  `%0` is the zeroth argument.  That's the name of the actual batch file itself.  If we run `program.bat` from the `C:\Folder\` directory, `%0` is probably `program.bat`.

The tidle (`~`) removes double quotes around the argument.  So `%~0` is the file name of the batch file without any quotation marks, which can appear if you have spaces in your file or folder names.

The `d` means "drive letter only".  So `%~d0` would be `C:` (assuming we're on the C: drive).

The `p` means "path only".  So `%~p0` would be `\Folder\`.

We want both, so `dp` means "drive and path only".  So `%~dp0` expands to `C:\Folder\`.

So, the first line of the batch file is now:

```
pushd C:\Folder\
```

But it's dynamic!  So if you move it to `D:\AnotherFolder\`, it will still work without needing to edit it.  You can find a full list of the variable modifications that cmd.exe understands under the [`for`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) command.

Comment: Thanks, for the info however I think I've realized what the issue is. I have mangy.bat, Main.exe and mangy.props. mangy.bat runs Main.exe which interacts with props.mangy. mangy.bat and Main.exe resolve fine because they're on the path. When Main.exe tries to open props.mangy it doesn't know where it is because it probably looks in the directory I'm currently in. What I probably need to do is set up Main.exe in a  way that it knows where to look for props.mangy properly. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. For anyone interested you can see what I did at https://github.com/RyanBluth/Mangy-Bat/tree/master/Mangy

Answer (score 2):

You can also add `.bat` files to `PATH` though the control panel:

---

Hit the windows key <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>, and start typing `environment`.

Click enter on the control panel option:

[image: Menu]

Click on `environment variables`:

[image: Control panel]

Scroll down to `Path`, and click `edit`:

[image: Path]

Then click `new`, and enter the folder of the batch file.

---

If your file is named `abc.bat`, and it is in your `PATH`, you can run it from CMD with:

```
abc
```