# How to make a batch script to execute from anywhere?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to run my batch script from anywhere, for example:

```
C:\>test123
```

And that command line executes my batch script `C:\Documents\test123.bat`.

I tried to do it with environment variable `path`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add batch file to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574800/add-batch-file-to-path)

Comment: After you add a directory to your path you have to exit the cmd window and start a new one because the old one still has the old path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your bat to PATH and make sure PATHEXT contains .BAT

[How to add your program to the PATH env variable](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)

Note, that the current working directory will be whereever you called it from.
If you want relative paths to where the bat is stored, use `%~dp0`

Please post the output of `echo %PATHEXT% %PATH%` and tell us the exact location of your bat file and more error info why it failed in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to C:\Windows\System32

Worked for Me.

System info:
Windows 10 with Admin access.